# How can i remove query string from the url using htaccess file in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to remove the query string from the URL. When I visit the page http://example.com/index.php it adds query to the url as http://example.com/index.php?i=1.

How to remove these query strings from URL?

Comment: you don't need `htaccess` in this case you have a link or redirect that define this argument as a get request

Comment: _“When I visit the page `http://example.com/index.php` it adds query to the url as `http://example.com/index.php?i=1`”_ - that isn’t a thing that happens magically by itself, you must have configured or scripted that behavior somewhere.